# How to create SearchView in RecyclerView using data from String.xml

Tags: arraylist, android-recyclerview, searchview

How can I create search view in Recycler View from string.xml using the following?

```
 private void setSearchModels() {
   String[] searchItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.search_items);
    for (int i = 0; i < searchItems.length; i++) {
    searchModels.add(new SearchModel(searchItems[i]));

    }
 It is frustrating and I am getting no help from Stack overflow.
It is working fine if we add items in Main Activity using:
obj.setholder() etc 
 return holder
```

but may be if I take data from string.xml searchview is returning null.